# The command is not supported from the UI:GET error in Snowflake UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created Snowflake Stage named 'mystage' and trying to unload data to my local LINUX device using the following command :

```
get @mystage/unload/data_0_0_0.csv.gz file:///home/blahblah/Documents
```

Upon running the above command I am getting the following error :

> SQL compilation error: The command is not supported from the UI: GET

I couldnt find any documentation about alternatives, so any help would be appreciated.

Sagar

Comment: you cannot put/get files to your local stages via WebUI, as per the error message. You ether need to use the SnowSQL tool, to put files into your local stage, or use an external tool to put file into a external stage/file like an AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: Hi , try this in SnowSQL it should work, check this link https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007r3NloSAE/the-command-is-not-supported-from-the-ui-put

Answer (score 1):

Commands GET/PUT cannot be run via WebUI:

> [GET](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/get.html)
>
> **Usage Notes**
>
> **The command cannot be executed from the Worksheets Worksheet tab page in the Snowflake web interface;**
>
> instead, use the [**SnowSQL client**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) to download data files, or check the documentation for the specific Snowflake client to verify support for this command.